# Multiple Oracle Data Export to individual spreadsheet in a single excel using C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have 10 Select queries in Oracle PL/SQl(each will return atleast 1000 records). How can I export Each Select Query Data returned in a separate(multiple) spreadsheets in a Single Excel File like Data returned from Query1 should be in spreadsheet1 and  data returned from Query2 should be in spreadsheet2 like wise using C#.net.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use a library like [NPIO](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), which can create and manipulate Excel files. Follow their tutorial at http://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html in order to create "worksheets" within the "workbook".